# How does COUNT(*) behave in an inner join

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Take this query:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.AccountNumber, COUNT(*) AS CountOfOrders,
    SUM(s.TotalDue) AS SumOfTotalDue
FROM Sales.Customer AS c
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderheader AS s ON c.CustomerID = s.CustomerID
GROUP BY c.CustomerID, c.AccountNumber
ORDER BY c.CustomerID;
```

I expected COUNT(*) to count the rows in Sales.Customer but to my surprise it counts the number of rows in the joined table.

Any idea why this is? Also, is there a way to be explicit in specifying which table COUNT() should operate on?

Comment: it will count all the rows from the result of join. Maybe you want `COUNT(DISTINCT c.CustomerID)`

Comment: Ahhh im with you.  The result of the join is a new table! Got it now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query Processing Order...

The FROM clause is processed before the SELECT clause -- which is to say -- by the time SELECT comes into play, there is only one (virtual) table it is selecting from -- namely, the individual tables *after* their joined (JOIN), filtered (WHERE), etc.

If you just want to count over the one table, then you might try a couple of things...

```
COUNT(DISTINCT table1.id)
```

Or turn the table you want to count into a sub-query with count() inside of it